# 301 Redirect old subdomain to new domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a strungle redirecting my old page to a new page.

When I redirect like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?final\.sanmarco\.cz$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^xyz\.php($|/) http://www.povrchyfinal.cz%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

It redirects to `http://www.povrchyfinal.cz/final/` instead of `http://www.povrchyfinal.cz/`

Comment: Provide an example as to what you want to redirect and to what?

Comment: I want to redirect final.sanmarco.cz (which after loading redirects itself to final.sanmarco.cz/final/) to povrchyfinal.cz

Comment: Remove the `%{REQUEST_URI}` from your `RewriteRule` directive.

Comment: nothing changed .. it still redirects to http://www.povrchyfinal.cz/final/ instead of http://www.povrchyfinal.cz/ .. Do I have to wait some time before the change appers or is it instant?

Comment: You've cached your redirect by using `R=301` which is correct but while testing code you should use `302` temporary so that its not cached. Then when it works change it to `301`. Clear your browser cache and it should work.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. I did 
RedirectMatch 301 /final/index.php http://povrchyfinal.cz/
and it works, so thank you :-)